# Bootstrap Row Centering Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, spacing

I am using the latest Bootstrap 3 to draft a site for a friend and I am having an issue centering items on the page. Normally I would do something like this:

```
.center{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but that is having no effect.

What I would like to do is set the desktop view up like this:

```
item    item    item
    item    item
```

And have the tablet view like this

```
item    item
item    item
    item
```

But the result I am getting is all the items are shifting left.

You can check out the site [here](http://bit.ly/1w1IDBr).

Comment: .center{text-align: center;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your row needs to be surrounded by `.container`

Secondly, to achieve that, just do offsets for your column?

So I'd generally do this:

```
.row
   .col-md-4.text-center    //.text-center  is to center your text and image within the column
   .col-md-4.text-center
   .col-md-4.text-center

.row
   .col-md-4.col-md-offset-2.text-center
   .col-md-4.text-center
```

Comment: This was an embarrassingly easy fix! I'm now ashamed i didn't think to tweak the grid with an offest. Thank you SOO much.

Answer (score 0):

First in your CSS:

```
.center{text-align: center;}
```

then in your HTML, change your last column to

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

remember that you want Bootstrap to adjust that last column to full width on tablets, and tablet size is `sm-` hence you need to add `sm-12` for anything tablet and smaller.

Comment: I'm laughing at myself over how easy this fix was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap has this utility built in.

```
 <div class="centered">
```